# Sum array columns if the array rows have different length

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list, sum

I'd like to know if it possible to sum the columns of an array if the rows have different length.

This is the array I want to sum:

```
input_val = [[1, 2, 3, 5],
             [1, 2, 3],
             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

And this would be the result:

```
output_val = [3, 6, 9, 9, 5]
```

I thought about the possibility of adding zeros to the rows:

```
input_val = [[1, 2, 3, 5, 0],
             [1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
             [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

And then sum the columns, but maybe is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the zero-padding easily and implicitly with [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(map(sum, itertools.zip_longest(*input_val, fillvalue=0)))
[3, 6, 9, 9, 5]
```

On python-2.x the function had a different name [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) and you don't need the `list` cast:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> map(sum, itertools.izip_longest(*input_val, fillvalue=0))
[3, 6, 9, 9, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to do this in python 2.7?

Comment: @SergieManchado In python 2.7 `zip_longest()` was named `izip_longest()`

Answer (score 2):

Adding zeros it's ok I think.

Also, you could do that:

```
sum_list = [sum(filter(None, i)) for i in map(None, *input_val)]
```

With `filter(None)` you are avoiding the None/out of index values.

Hope it will help you.

EDIT: This only works on python-2.x. It will throw an exception on python-3.x.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this only works on python-2.x. It will throw an exception on python-3.x

Answer (score 2):

While `map` works fine, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45430549/7738328) it is generally consider more 'Pythonic' to use list comprehension (to the same effect):

```
import itertools
[sum(col) for col in itertools.zip_longest(*input_val, fillvalue=0)]
```

Here the array is effectively transposed using the `zip(* ...)` construct. With the normal `zip()` operator, the shortest column will decide the length. However, with `itertools.zip_longest()` it is possible to use the longest column as the length, filling the others with the `fillvalue`.

In effect, this is exactly the solution proposed in the original post, just implemented in a refined manner.

Answer (score 2):

A numpy solution

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as itt
np.sum(np.array(list(itt.zip_longest(*input_val, fillvalue=0)), int), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need pandas for this, which makes your life easier:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas
>>> i = pandas.DataFrame(input_val).fillna(0).values.astype(numpy.int32)
>>> i
array([[1, 2, 3, 5, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], dtype=int32)
>>> i.sum(axis=0)
array([3, 6, 9, 9, 5])
```